# Websockets or polling for triggering occasional client side callbacks from redis

Tags: javascript, websocket, event-handling, polling, server-push

I'm trying to figure out the best way for my client apps (angular) to have a callback (with data) triggered from a server event. My current scheme is this:

- client app uploads a document (not a very frequent operation)
- regular rest server receives it, and dispatches it to a worker over an amqp queue, where many version are generated and shuffled around S3 (could take a while)
- when workers are done, a message is sent, ultimately meant to trigger a callback in the client side app

Issues:
- we will have many cooperating apps on different machines
- we have to support IE9

The simplest solution seems to be that the workers put the result into redis, and the client app polls another server-app who's only job is to hand back results from redis (json params and a token to a callback to fire). If this "answer callback server" does nothing else, it can be plenty fast and tweaked for polling. In our case, the only server push events will be *responses* to something the client occasionally initiates. So a client only really needs to poll if they have a) uploaded a file and b) not gotten their response yet. We don't need all clients polling all the time for random server events (like you would for chat, say). I wonder if this means that vanilla short-polling would be fine, or are there advantages to using websockets or long polling that I'm not aware of? Any suggestions or pointers to resources welcome.